# DHTMLX Gantt APIs

Tags: javascript, java, gantt-chart, dhtmlx

I have been working with DhtmlxGantt which uses javascript. I was hoping to perform some calculation such as milestones, progress, and days. I was wondering if I can perform this calculation with DhtmlxGantt APIs java instead of javascript. The reason I would prefer using java is mainly due to data security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DHTMLX Gantt is a Javascript library. There is no way to use Java methods inside Gantt. 
However, in the 7.0 version, it will be possible to run Gantt on the server-side without DOM. You can contact the support team to learn more about it.